# Is there a way to keep this redstone separated?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

Is there a way for me to connect these parallel redstone lines to their respective redstone torches without interference?

EDIT: Its preferable that it has a repeater too.
[image: Image of redstone separated by 1 block]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

This is the easiest way, just using the bit of flexibility of a redstone torch tower. Use of repeaters doesn't really help in this scenario.

Check [a related question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/380826/how-to-make-one-wide-tileable-vertical-redstone-in-minecraft/380836#380836) for other solutions you might adapt.