# Hopper disabling with redstone

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I recently run into problems regarding disabling hoppers. I would like to disable the three hoppers individually. But I am unable to achieve this.

Extra space between the chests/hoppers is no solution for me :/ I have tried adding a repeater, but that does not work with hoppers.

Just to clarify: This is just an example in a test world. In my main world, I have a long line of redstone between the three lever and the hoppers. And the hoppers will be combined as shown in the picture, to one hopper line.

Thanks for you help!

[image: Front View]
[image: Back View]

Answer (score 7):

Welcome to the world of 1-wide tileable contraptions.

Redstone dust is one of worst choices, very restricting - you need a very precise distance from power source to the receiver, equal to the power level of the source. Most sources produce signal strength 15, so that's not very convenient; sources of weaker signal tend to be rather inconvenient.

[image]

Another rather inconvenient option is to split the signal vertically:

[image]

For short distances repeaters are a decent option, but with delay they produce that's not always viable.

[image]

Or use the sticky blocks - again, not getting them stick to what you don't want them to stick to is a bit of pain - the redstone blocks are glued to the side because if they were at the end, adjacent redstone blocks would stick to the extended "branch":

[image]

Your more convenient alternatives are various 1-tileable transports - with the caveat that most of them operate in pulse logic (odd pulse = 1, even pulse = 0) - and require a dual edge detector to get converted from standard binary logic (signal = 1, lack of signal = 0) and a T flip-flop to "rectify" them back into it. Luckily the easiest dual edge detector is an observer, and the easiest T flip-flop is a sticky piston with a redstone block. Still, they are definitely practical:

- Powered and Activator rails

[image]

And if you want fancier shapes, observer transport is an option. Use indirectly powered noteblocks for corner pieces, padding, and to reduce the general cost. Either forward signal directly observer-to-observer, or power the noteblocks indirectly - otherwise signal from directly powered block will "spill over" to the adjacent blocks.

[image]
[image]

There's a lot more to 1-wide tileable builds, and they are a graceful, broad subject - [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/380826/how-to-make-one-wide-tileable-vertical-redstone-in-minecraft/380836#380836) covers a good bit about vertical signal transport.

Comment: Maybe not practicle, but I love the sticky one

Comment: @pinckerman It's actually very practical for vertical transport, and pretty decent if you need to "reach around a corner".

Comment: Good to know, I definitely must try that.

Comment: @pinckerman Watch out for quasi-connectivity when transmitting downwards. Generally what QC broke, QC can fix; if you use pistons to extend the signal, powered from above, power them through QC, noteblocks on top to provide the updates.